# mysql query order by last post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

dHello can you help me with a query about ordering the topics by most recent posts? i mean that i want a topic to go on top when someone post on it. Here are the tables:

**Discussion**

- id_discution
- name
- id_category
- date

**Comments**

- id_comment
- id_user
- description
- type
- id_discussion
- date (timestamp)

here is my code but i get duplicates of topics but they are orderd good

```
select discussion.id_discution, discussion.name, discussion.id_category, 
    discussion.date, discussion.report, comments.id_comment, comments.id_pet_dem_des, 
    comments.date,comments.type 
from discussion,comments 
where discussion.id_discution=comments.id_discussion 
    AND type=3
order by comments.id_comment  desc
```

Comment: Your title refers to the order but your question says the order is fine and you have an issue with duplicates. What's the real issue here?

Comment: cause i want to order only by last comment added for each topic not for all comments related to those topics cause then i get example "topic1 topic2 topic2 topic1 topic3 topic2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` the discussion table's primary key...

```
SELECT
  discussion.id_discution, discussion.name, discussion.id_category, discussion.date, discussion.report
FROM
  discussion
INNER JOIN
  comments
    ON  discussion.id_discution = comments.id_discussion
    AND type=3
GROUP BY
  discussion.id_discution
ORDER BY
  MAX(comments.date)  desc
```

Note: I don't include any data from the `comments` table in the `SELECT` clause.

This is because you only want each discussion to appear once, but each discussion can have many comments.  You either have the discussion appear many times, and include the comments, or you don't include the comments data in the results.

You *could* include aggregate values, such as `COUNT(*)` to show how many comments there are `MAX(comments.date)` to show how recently the discussion was commented on, etc, etc.

Comment: This answer uses `ANSI-92` syntax with `INNER JOIN` because 20 years should be good enough for a standard to settle down.  *(Not to mention that all providers now suggest not to use `,` syntax any more...)*

Comment: hey thxn for the answer, it's working good now:), i didnt use inner join cause i remember from some univ course that is not good for sql optimization, i'm not sure if i remember good, but anyway thnx it's working as it should now:D

Comment: @SimaCristianAlexandru . . . Your university course was wrong.  In fact, the proper syntax can only help the SQL engine find the best optimization for the query.

Comment: Although this _is_ mySQL specific, because most (all?) other RDBMS providers will call you out for not aggregating/grouping all the columns selected.  Although you should be okay here, so long as only columns from `discussion` are used, and nothing from `comments` (and there are no duplicates of `discussion.id`, of course).

Comment: @x-zero - `All` may be true.  But as used here I quite like the functionality.  Had the query reference the comments table I would prefer MySQL to throw an error though.  Powerful, put sloppily implemented *(in my opinion)*.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, here's an example that should work for all RDBMS providers (although apparently DB2 reserves `COMMENT` and `TYPE`...):

```
SELECT Discussion.discussionId, Discussion.title, 
       Discussion.categoryId, Discussion.startedAt -- + other columns
FROM Discussion
LEFT JOIN (SELECT discussionId, MAX(madeAt) as madeAt
           FROM Comment
           WHERE type = 3
           GROUP BY discussionId) as Most_Recent
ON Most_Recent.discussionId = Discussion.discussionId
ORDER BY COALESCE(Most_Recent.madeAt, Discussion.startedAt) DESC
```

(have a working SQLFiddle [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed188/2).)

Other notes:

- Don't just label things as 'date' - try to be specific - and don't label them with their datatypes, either.  Use something like `startedAt`, etc, to make it clear.
- I believe the usual practice is to use `<entity_name> + 'Id'`, not the other way around (at least, most people will be expecting this format).
- Try to be consistent with whether your entity (table) names are singular or plural.  There's apparently been holy wars fought over this, but most of the recommendations I've seen say to make them singular (named after a *row* in the table, not the collection as a whole).
- As mentioned earlier, exclusively use explicit joins, don't use the comma-separated `FROM` clause (you're okay during `INNER JOIN`s, usually, but things get weird outside of that, so practice proper behavior for those times).